# Mount anywhere and tell me about it

Tags: linux, mount, unmount

I want to write a script that does the following:

- Mount a device (always the same one)
- Take a peek at a file at the device and tell me something about it
- Unmount the device again.

This is fairly easy, but I fear about the mounting point: **What if somebody (me?) already has mounted something at that point or dropped files at it?**

Would it be possible to tell the script something like the following pseudo code:

```
$whereToGo = mount /dev/device --justMountItSomewhereWhereItIsPossibleAndTellMeWhereThatIs
// Do something with $whereToGo/myFile
umount $whereToGo
```

Comment: try to create a new folder, may be a random folder and try to mount on that mount point.

Comment: Why not just use Disks / Gnome Disk Utility? It's GUI and doesn't mount things on top of other things

Comment: @OmPS: You mean, I would have to do all the work (generate path, check if the path can be used and redo if not, mount there) by myself?

Comment: @Xen2050: I often have no such GUIs, for example when working over SSH only.

Answer (score 1):

Gnome disk utility uses udisks2, looks like `udisksctl` is it's command line tool, it can do things like:

```
status
    Shows high-level information about disk drives and block devices.

info
    Shows detailed information about OBJECT or DEVICE.

mount
    Mounts a device. The device will be mounted in a subdirectory in the /media
    hierarchy - upon successful completion, the mount point will be printed to
    standard output.

    The device will be mounted with a safe set of default options. You can
    influence the options passed to the mount(8) command with --options.
    Note that only safe options are allowed - requests with inherently unsafe
    options such as suid or dev that would allow the caller to gain additional
    privileges, are rejected.

unmount
    Unmounts a device. This only works if the device is mounted. The option
    --force can be used to request that the device is unmounted even if active
    references exists.
```

If the mountpoint already exists, udksks2 will create & use a new mountpoint (probably by appending a `1`).

So you should be able to write a script something like this (using /dev/loop5 as an example):

```
$ udisksctl mount --block-device /dev/loop5
Mounted /dev/loop5 at /media/demo/675584e8-d292-4c69-96d6-0fdb720bdf93.

# parse stdout for the mount point, do something with it

$ udisksctl unmount --block-device /dev/loop5
Unmounted /dev/loop5.
```

*(Could even mount read-only by adding `--options ro` to `udisksctl mount`)*

---

Info from arch's [archwiki on Udisks - Mount Helpers](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udisks#Mount_helpers)

> ### Mount helpers
>
> The automatic mounting of devices is easily achieved with udisks wrappers. See also [List of applications#Mount tools](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/List_of_applications#Mount_tools).
>
> > Note: Desktop environments, such as GNOME and KDE may also provide a udisk wrapper.
>
> - bashmount — A bash script to mount and manage removable media as a regular user with udisks2.
>     https://github.com/jamielinux/bashmount
> - udiskie — udisks2 automounter with optional notifications, tray icon and support for password protected [LUKS devices](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Device_encryption). See the [udiskie wiki](https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie/wiki/Usage) for details
>     https://github.com/coldfix/udiskie
> - udisksvm — GUI udisks2 wrapper written in Python3 and using the Qt5 framework. It uses mouse clicks to mount, unmount removable devices or eject a CD/DVD. See the [README](https://github.com/berbae/udisksvm/blob/master/README) file for details.
>     https://github.com/berbae/udisksvm
> - udevil — Includes devmon, which is compatible to udisks and udisks2.
>     https://github.com/IgnorantGuru/udevil

Comment: Would be great, but I do not have that tool.

Comment: @Bowi just install it, the package is in Debian, Arch, Gentoo, probably available for every Linux distribution. The [archwiki on Udisks](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/udisks) suggests some helper scripts  that might be worth a look too, I'll edit them into the answer.